# Print the edges (points) of undirected graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

How I can print the  points : I mean "(x,y)"  of a cycle in a graph ?
. I am stuck there. I don't know how to print the points that are on the cycle.

Comment: The term "graph" is used in multiple contexts. In one context a graph is a plot that illustrates the relation between two (or more) values. I believe that in your context, it is a collection of vertices and edges, and vertices don't have any x,y coordinate. It's also very likely that I'm misunderstanding your question, as it's not very clear to me.

Comment: I mean (i,j) 
and every edge  has ( i,j) point ..

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the algorithm you are running as movements along the graph. In order to detect a cycle, you check every possible movement from a starting position whether it brings you back to the starting position. This you do recursively for any adjacent vertex. Now, when you detect a cycle, your path resembles the recursive calls that you made.

A few notes:

- Since this is clearly homework, I'm not giving you a full solution but enough of a hint.
- If you have trouble imagining this as movement, print the current position at different points during program execution.
- I don't think your algorithm is implemented correctly. Make sure that you have a few test cases to verify that it does what it should.